# How to convert a simple DataFrame to a DataSet Spark Scala with case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a simple DataFrame to a DataSet from the example in Spark: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)    
import spark.implicits._

val path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"

val peopleDS = spark.read.json(path).as[Person]
peopleDS.show()
```

But the following problem arises:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `age` from bigint to int as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- field (class: "scala.Int", name: "age")
- root class: ....
```

Can anyone help me out?

Edit
I noticed that with Long instead of Int works!
Why is that?

Also:

```
val primitiveDS = Seq(1,2,3).toDS()
val augmentedDS = primitiveDS.map(i => ("var_" + i.toString, (i + 1).toLong))
augmentedDS.show()

augmentedDS.as[Person].show()
```

Prints:

```
+-----+---+
|   _1| _2|
+-----+---+
|var_1|  2|
|var_2|  3|
|var_3|  4|
+-----+---+

Exception in thread "main"
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`name`' given input columns: [_1, _2];
```

Can Anyone Help me out understand here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change Int to Long (or BigInt) it works fine:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
import spark.implicits._

val path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"

val peopleDS = spark.read.json(path).as[Person]
peopleDS.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

EDIT:
`Spark.read.json` by default parses numbers as `Long` types - it's safer to do so.
You can change the col type after using casting or udfs.

EDIT2:

To answer your 2nd question, you need to name the columns correctly before the conversion to Person will work:

```
val primitiveDS = Seq(1,2,3).toDS()
val augmentedDS = primitiveDS.map(i => ("var_" + i.toString, (i + 1).toLong)).
 withColumnRenamed ("_1", "name" ).
 withColumnRenamed ("_2", "age" )
augmentedDS.as[Person].show()
```

Outputs:

```
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|var_1|  2|
|var_2|  3|
|var_3|  4|
+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create dataset from case class

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
```

Keep the case class outside of the class that has below code

```
val primitiveDS = Seq(1,2,3).toDS()
val augmentedDS = primitiveDS.map(i => Person("var_" + i.toString, (i + 1).toLong))
augmentedDS.show()

augmentedDS.as[Person].show()
```

Hope this helped

Comment: No! They aren't! I have only 3 values: null, 30, and 19!